# Check Out In Magento 2 Rest API Using Paypal

Tags: magento2, api, paypal

How can we check out using the Magento 2 Rest API with the Paypal payment method?

Answer (score 1):

As this is quite a broad question, rather than trying to fully explain an implementation, I will direct you to thorough documentation which will 1) help you get simple examples working, and then 2) allow you to extend until you reach your solution.

Please see the Magento 2 developer documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/. In particular, you will interested in the sections "Get Started with Magento APIs" and "REST API Reference (Static)". You first goal should be to use a machine from another network to receive a REST response from your Magento instance.

As far as PayPal, this will potentially become complicated. First of all, I would ensure that you have PayPal properly configured with a normal checkout in your browser. Again, configuring PayPal in itself requires jumping through a few hoops. You will make the required changes in the admin area under Stores>Configuration>Sales>Payment Methods. The community user documentation provides a [thorough description of Magento's capabilities with PayPal](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/payment/paypal.html).

If you have these two steps working, you will likely have a good understanding of both REST and Paypal configuration. At that point, you should be able to ask more targeted questions to the forums, for instance, asking why you are receiving specific errors from PayPal, or how to structure your module to handle the REST request.

Good luck - this is a significant amount of work you are taking on. Feel free to present your findings to the community in the form of a blog post or even an extension.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem find out the approach we have use ...

[Check Out In Magento 2 Rest API Using Paypal](http://www.ipragmatech.com/validate-payment-paypal-magento-rest-api/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the below to run a post query  replace runPostQuery with your curl request. this will pass a token that already has been successful to magento 2.

```
 $payment['paymentMethod'] = ['method' =>'paypal_express',
               'additional_data' => array (
                   'paypal_express_checkout_token' => $request->query->get('token'),
                   'paypal_express_checkout_redirect_required' => false,
                   'paypal_express_checkout_payer_id' => $request->query->get('PayerID')
               )];


           $completedPayment = $this->runPostQuery('carts/mine/payment-information', $headers, json_encode($payment));
```